# Odds of predicting the flop (twice!!)

Tags: texas-hold-em

At a weekly pub tournament game, final table, TD is dealing for the table.

Hand 1, he calls out (predicts) the flop cards, values only, not suits.
eg: 9, Queen, 3

He then turns over the flop cards, and they come out in that exact order.

What are the odds?

Three hands later, he does the same, calls out (predicts) the flop cards, values only, not suits.
eg: King, 9, Jack

He then turns over the flop cards, and they come out in that exact order. Again!

What are the odds?

Comment: The odds are pretty high that he also called out dozens of flops that didn't hit, and you just didn't seem to remember those.

Comment: No he only called out the two flops and got them both right

Answer (score 2):

So I am at my weekly game right now and showed the TD this post.

He came clean with his 'cheat.'

As folks are betting preflop around the table he has the deck in his hands and is surreptitiously flipping the corners of the top few cards, thus giving him the info on what the flop cards are!

Comment: I would never play in this game ever again.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that hard of a move to keep a few cards were you need them in a deck. Shame on the TD he was doing magic tricks at the table. So the odds are ***TILTED***